# How to get a Javascript Array url attribute to accept a regex prefix for a variable

Tags: javascript

first question here, hope I don't get clobbered..

It's regarding JS and how to pass Regex values in an array.
So in my code:

```
var cube = generateCubeMap(  mapId  , 100 );
```

Where mapId is just a changing number and the 2nd param is also not important.
Later on though, a function is created for the above:

```
function generateCubeMap( folderName, tileWidth )
```

and inside it there's an array with an attribute of:

```
url: './textures/cube/' + folderName + '/front.jpg',
```

*To summarize*

I need to get to the point where front.jpg would be accepted with any prefixes, so for example: any-characeter.front.jpg (to include the suffixing dot.)

> This is obviously wrong:

```
url: './textures/cube/' +/^[^ /]+$/+ folderName + '/front.jpg',
```

I get from my console:

> http://localhost/public/master/examples/textures/cube//%5E[%5E%20//]+$/7/front.jpg
>    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

***So how does one make an array's attribute (url) accept a regex that accepts anything-before.front.jpg ?***

Comment: Though it may be easy to code a regexp for almost any expression, the problem may arise when it comes to _use it_. What do you want to do later with that `url`?

Comment: It would be a good idea to post the part of your code that is using `url`. That may help people work out how to have that string interpreted as a regex for you. Which webserver are you using? Express.js? Hapi.js?

Comment: @peregrine42 hi -I already wrote that the url is an attribute that is part of of an array, that part is fine and I put the url attribute as is.

Comment: Hi @LittleSanti - I have an app that creates filenames like this: whatever.front.jpg, i'm just looking to diregard anything behind front.jpg, to include the "."

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you strip the prefixes before you set the URL

```
url: './textures/cube/' + folderName.split("/").pop() + '/front.jpg',
```

assuming that prefixes are separated by "/"

Comment: there are no "/" prefix, only what i wrote . I've tried to use "." but the error was that: "Uncaught TypeError: folderName.split is not a function"

Comment: @MYZ what are the possible values that `folderName` could take?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `url` attribute of your object is being used as a regex somewhere, you can have that regex accept any folder name by using the following expression:

```
url: './textures/cube/^[^/?\. ]+$/front.jpg',
```

No need to include the folder name in the regex, because the regex is general - it'll match anything for that segment of the path.

I've excluded slashes, spaces, question marks and dots from the pattern - any other character will match. This follows the URL spec here:

https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-code-points

EDIT:

sorry, to answer your question:

> So how does one make an array accept an [anything-regex.]front.jpg ?

You can use the following:

```
[^/? ]*\.?front.jpg
```

That matches string of characters (that are not a `/`, `?` or space), takes an optional `.`, then expects `front.jpg`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, but it's still not showing, I get this from the console: localhost/public/master/examples/textures/cube
/%5E[%5E%20/]+$/7/front.jpg
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)